# Mongoose populate Schema returns undefined

Tags: node.js, mongoose, population

I have a little problem with nesting some sub documents with mongoose. I read a lot about this and tried nearly everything.

I really don't know what is wrong.
I know there are really much questions about this in the web.A lot of them are similar, but nothing solved my problem.

The problem is, that my populated document always is empty.

- I checked my Schemas
- I deleted the whole Database
- After that i rewrote the whole schemas and codes again.

Nothing helped.
I think it is a really small problem, but i do not get it.

## Here are my Schemas:

probe.js

```
const ProbeShema = new mongoose.Schema({
        device: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Device'
        },
        value: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
                enum: ['Energy', 'Consumption', 'Voltage', 'Current', 'Frequency', 'Time', 'Date']
        },
        unit: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
                enum: ['kWh', 'kW', 'V', 'A', 'Hz', 'time', 'date']
        },
        oid: {
                type: String,
                required: true
        },
        measurement: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Measurement'
        }
});

const Probe = mongoose.model('Probe', ProbeShema,'probe');
module.exports = Probe;
```

devices.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

const DeviceShema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
                trim: true
        },
        ip: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
                unique: true,
                trim: true
        },
        port: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
                trim: true
        },
        secret: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
                trim: true
        },
        probe: [{
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Probe'
        }]
});

const Device = mongoose.model('Device', DeviceShema,'device');
module.exports = Device;
```

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Device = require('../../models/devices')

Device.find()
   .populate( 'probe')
   .exec()
   .then(devices => {
         console.log(devices)
         res.render('./snmp/snmp', { "title": "SNMP-Devices", "devices": devices });
     })
     .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
     });
```

## Output:

```
[{
probe: [],
    _id: 5db94f22d8fb641c18fc05b9,
    name: 'test',
    ip: '1.11.1.1',
    port: '111',
    secret:
     '$2b$10$2umat9QqHSFF9/zVih9LU.UKX4sPh/Lmq5XjSai0/pt42QfLXQb6u',
    __v: 0 
}]
```

## What i excpect:

```
    _id: 5db94f22d8fb641c18fc05b9,
    name: 'test',
    ip: '1.11.1.1',
    port: '111',
    secret:
     '$2b$10$2umat9QqHSFF9/zVih9LU.UKX4sPh/Lmq5XjSai0/pt42QfLXQb6u',
    probe: [
    {
       device: '5db94f22d8fb641c18fc05b9',
       value: 'Energy',
       unit: 'kWh',
       oid:'1.1.1.1.11',
       measurement: 11
    },{
       device: '5db94f22d8fb641c18fc05b9',
       value: 'Consumption',
       unit: 'kW',
       oid:'1.1.1.1.12',
       measurement: 500
     }
]
```

## MongoDB documents

```
{
   "_id":"5db95821d3a65d20200cda64",
   "device":"5db9581fd3a65d20200cda63",
   "oid":"asd",
   "value":"Energy",
   "unit":"kWh","__v":0
}


{
   "_id":"5db9581fd3a65d20200cda63",
   "probe":[],
   "name":"asd",
   "ip":"1.1.1.1",
   "port":"1",
   "secret":"$2b$10$mr4x4ls0J2CqdNxnk/ih2.FAHpj1fsXT2NsgrzDXF9y4LCnZBNfXa",
   "__v":0
}
```

Comment: In your db, the probe array is empty?

Comment: sorry, maybe its not clear written. the last part shows the two documents. first one is the probe, second one the device. so there shoul be a probe

Comment: but the probe field in the device doesn't contain anything

Comment: oh... :/ your right. the entity shouldnt be listed there right?! the population do this automatic by reference to the probe document by id?! in other words: the probes arent listet in the document "device"  in the database.

Comment: Yes. the probe field should be an array of object id then the population will work

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly believe the problem arises because of the circular refs (device has ref to probe, probe has ref to device)

In device model I would remove the ref to the device.

probe.js ( I removed the ref to the device, and not included other fields for simplicity)

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const ProbeShema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    value: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      enum: [
        "Energy",
        "Consumption",
        "Voltage",
        "Current",
        "Frequency",
        "Time",
        "Date"
      ]
    }
  }
);


const Probe = mongoose.model("Probe", ProbeShema, "probe");
module.exports = Probe;
```

device.js ( I didn't included other fields for simplicity)

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

const DeviceShema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  probe: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Probe"
    }
  ]
});

const Device = mongoose.model("Device", DeviceShema, "device");
module.exports = Device;
```

With these changes, now you can get the devices with probes like this:

```
router.get("/device", async (req, res) => {
  const devices = await Device.find({}).populate("probe");

  res.send(devices);
});
```

This will give you a resultset like this:

```
[
    {
        "probe": [
            {
                "_id": "5db96a460ef8cc1c9c45e7f4",
                "value": "Energy",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "5db96aa30ef8cc1c9c45e7f5",
                "value": "Consumption",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ],
        "_id": "5db96f13d8faa752cc9e2cf9",
        "name": "Device 1",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "probe": [
            {
                "_id": "5db96a460ef8cc1c9c45e7f4",
                "value": "Energy",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "5db96aa30ef8cc1c9c45e7f5",
                "value": "Consumption",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "5db96f96b59c3139bce431bd",
                "value": "Voltage",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ],
        "_id": "5db96fb1b59c3139bce431be",
        "name": "Device 2",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
Device.aggregate([
// Unwind the source
{ "$unwind": "$devices" },
// Do the lookup matching
{ "$lookup": {
   "from": "probe",
   "localField": "probe",
   "foreignField": "_id",
   "as": "proeObjects"
}},
// Unwind the result arrays ( likely one or none )
{ "$unwind": "$proeObjects" },
// Group back to arrays
{ "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "devices": { "$push": "$devices" },
    "proeObjects": { "$push": "$proeObjects" }
}}
], (err, result) => { console.log(err || )})
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help.
I was really misunderstanding something. It gets from time to time clearer.
The code itself wasn't wrong at it self i think.

The Problem was, that populating not is working as i expect.
I have to test and play with this a little bit to learn more about this. 
It seems still not to be clear to me.
I'm coming from MySQL, which handling is completely different.

I have a lot of trouble about how to save constraints between different models and so on. I thought that populate just compares the id,and then nesting it, but that's not the case. (!?)

It seems to work now, because i added the id's in the array probs.

There are a lot of question for me, but i have to answer them by myself.
Its really hard when you think you are so near on target and see the light in the end of the tunnel, but in fact you just arrived the tunnel ^^

Thanks for all and sorry for waiting time and my bad English.

Best regards

Comment: If any of the answers helped you, please mark as answer or upvote.